# About light weight of .net core app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I just finish a small app, using .NET Core to see.

I'm at the publishing moment and in the publish directory there are 66 files!

My app itself is a **47 Ko** dll. All right, I use efcore and newtonsoft json, but I have **14 Mo** of various dll (such as System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll) to deploy.

The same .NET (not Core) app would have been much more lighter.

My question is: what do I miss, because according to [.NET Core Application Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/):

> The size of your deployment package is small. You only have to deploy
>   your app and its dependencies, not .NET Core itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct and nothing to worry about. Unlike .NET Framework, .NET Core is modular and fetched via NuGet. So there is no fat runtime which needs to be installed.

There are two major type of applications in .NET Core:

#### portable applications

Portable applications require a runtime to be installed. Everything not part of the runtime will be shipped as packages.

Or to be more specific: Everything not included in [Microsoft.NETCore.App](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App/) or [NETStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/) (both are meta packages which only reference common Runtime libraries) or one of it's dependencies, will be downloaded via nuget and packaged with your application.

#### self-contained applications

Self-contained applications allow you to run and deploy .NET Core applications w/o installing the framework. In this case **all** dependencies (including runtime assemblies) will be packaged with your application. This allows multiple application to run side by side using different versions of .NET Core w/o i.e. an update affecting the programs functionality.

Additionally you also have native dependencies, which depend on native libraries (i.e. OpenSSL on Linux or CryptoAPI on Windows), which will be also shipped via nuget and packaged in your deployments.

Answer (score 1):

It's light weight in that you don't need the massive .NET Framework installed on the machine running your app.

I just looked on my local machine in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 and it is 582 files and nearly 200 MB.

If you use the Self-contained deployment (SCD) method then you will even more than 66 files, but then you won't even need the .NET Core Runtime installed- making it truly stand alone (i.e. "self-contained").