# What does lightweight mean in .net Core

Tags: .net-core, standards

I am reading an ebook about Docker and Microservices. It referred the .net core was lightweight compared with traditional .net standard.

I don't quite get the story behind it. Can someone give some explanation about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because .Net Core is optimized for microservices and dockers.

In short, .Net Core doesn't offer as many things as another classic implementation of .Net Standard, reducing its size which even allows for an app to be packaged with all dependencies (and so not needing any installation of .Net on the running machine). This is why I think it could be called lightweight.

See :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt842506.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

[About light weight of .net core app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333411/about-light-weight-of-net-core-app)

Answer (score 0):

> I am reading an ebook about Docker and Microservices. It referred the
> .net core was lightweight compared with traditional .net standard.

I think here you are referring to .net core is lightweight than .net frameworks as .net standard are just API specifications for implementing base class libraries by different frameworks.

Please refer to below link for more information:
https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/dotnet-core-standard-difference/
https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/net-core-vs-net-framework-a694f1fbdb26

Now coming back to why .net core framework is lightweight .net 4.5 or other frameworks as it's modular. When you create or run an application you don't need to install all dependencies which you do not need unlike .net 4.5 or other frameworks where everything is installed.

Basically, .Net framework has been split into individual pieces implemented using CoreFX for .net core framework which makes .Net core lightweight.
Link for details - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dotnet_core/dotnet_core_managed_extensibility_framework.htm